# Error Code: 1265

Tags: mysql

Me podrian ayudar con lo siguiente? Al momento de insertar el registro da un error code 1265 en la columna _tipoHabitacion.

```
/*Habitacion*/
        DESCRIBE habitacion;
    DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE if EXISTS p_InsertarHabitacionHotel;
            CREATE PROCEDURE p_InsertarHabitacionHotel
            (
            IN _idHabitacion INT,
            IN _idHotel INT,
            in _TipoHabitacion ENUM('Individual(1)','Doble(2)','Triple(3)','Familiar(5)','Suite(2-4)'),
            IN _precioHabitacion decimal,
            IN _descripcion VARCHAR(150)
            )
            BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 call p_ErrorHandlerHoteles(1062);
            INSERT INTO habitacion VALUES(_idHabitacion,_idHotel,_TipoHabitacion,_precioHabitacion,_descripcion);
            END ;
        //

CALL p_InsertarHabitacionHotel(1, 1, 'Individual(1)', 100.00, 'Habitación individual con baño privado');
      CALL p_InsertarHabitacionHotel(2, 1, 'Doble(2)', 150.00, 'Habitación doble con dos camas individuales');
      CALL p_InsertarHabitacionHotel(3, 2, 'Triple(3)', 200.00, 'Habitación triple con tres camas individuales');
      CALL p_InsertarHabitacionHotel(4, 2, 'Familiar(5)', 250.00, 'Habitación familiar con una cama matrimonial y dos camas individuales');
      CALL p_InsertarHabitacionHotel(5, 3, 'Suite(2-4)', 300.00, 'Suite con capacidad para 2 a 4 personas, con sala de estar y balcón privado');
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. También sugiero que en tu publicación incluyas el mensaje de error exacto y completo y no solo su código o una descripción tuya, pues esto ayuda a identificar más fácilmente el problema a quienes conozcan la base de datos que usas. Un saludo.

Comment: También incluye la sentencia de creación de la tabla `habitacion`.